# remove white spaces between image and video

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

Here is the link that has white spaces between video and images.

[Link](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1559702/2feda0a0694cb8e1a8e8e95ec4c292ef)

**HTML:**

```
<video controls="" class="video-width-activity">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="tesp.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

**CSS:**

```
.video-width-activity {
   height: 450px;
}
```

If I apply below CSS:

```
.video-width-activity {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

then this is happening:

[New-Link](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1559712/a249c5ba5d5b068613df624fd16dfb28)

Is there any way to remove white spaces?

Comment: Can we have a fiddle to debug the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what the cause is but try changing height to auto

```
    .video-width-activity {
       height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: it is looking like this: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1559712/a249c5ba5d5b068613df624fd16dfb28

Comment: thank you for your response, I have used custom player instead of default video tag

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is because of some `margin` between the video and images on right. Remove margins if any.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have used custom player instead of default video tag